# Separate foreign-key linked model or a custom user model for User Settings in Django?

Tags: django, django-users

Would it be more efficient to create a custom user model if I want settings to be tied to the user (AbstractUser would be used)?

The other seemingly simpler option would be to create a Settings model in my main app and tie it to the user with a foreign key. Which would be more maintainable when the user-base grows?

Some examples of a few settings options would be private profile, hidden in search, profile pictures.

Comment: What is your question? The two are both valid ways to implement this.

Comment: I suppose which would be more maintainable when the user-base grows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Create a **Custom User Model**:

You should create a custom User Model extending AbstractUser when you use Django authentication process and need to add some extra information directly in the User model, without having to create another class.

---

### 2. Create a Settings Model in my main App and tie it to the User Model with a **OneToOneField**:

You should use a One-To-One Link as long as you have to store extra information about the existing User Model and it doesn't have anything to do with the authentication process.

---

Reference: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html